# How to produce a quarter plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a data set about workers and their wages. The description of the data is listed below:

- lwage : the log weekly wage of a worker
- educ : the worker’s years of education
- yob : the year in which the worker was born (1930~1940)
- qob : the quarter of the year in which the worker was born (1/2/3/4)

I am trying to make a plot like this:

[image]

where the x-axis is the yob, the y-axis is the educ, the dots show the qob, to investigate the relationship between the average years of completed education over years and quarters of birth.

Right now I can only think of using `plot(yob, educ)`, but I am uncertain how to add a third variable into a 2-d plot in R. May I ask how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of some imaginary data like the one depicted, and how to make it using R's built-in `plot` function.

```
set.seed(42)
yob = rep(1930:1940, each = 4)
qob = rep(4:1, times = 11)
yqob = yob - (qob-1)/4
age = 1970 - yqob
educ = 12 + 0.5 * (age-30) + 0.2 * qob * runif(44)  # arbitrary function to make similar pattern


# Plot
plot(age, educ, type = "l")                        # create line chart
text(age, educ, labels = qob, pos = 1, cex = 0.7)  # add text with parameters meaning:
   # x    y     label         below    smaller
```

[image]

I generally prefer using the `ggplot2` package for R plotting, which would look like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
my_data = data.frame(age, educ, qob)
ggplot(my_data, aes(age, educ, label = qob)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(vjust = 1.5) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]